# Extension function and Intermediate value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Let $f:(1,2) \to \Bbb R$ be a function with dense graph such that $f$ satisfies the intermediate value theorem. Define a function $h$ by $h(x)=f(x)$ on $(1,2)$ and $h(x)=0$ otherwise. Does $h$ still satisfy the intermediate value theorem? My answer yes,

Let $a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $a<b$ and $y\in\Bbb R$ such that $h(a)<y<h(b)$. We need to show that there exists $x\in(a,b)$ such that $h(x)=y.$ We can assume $h(b)>0$ and $h(a)=0.$ Then, by density of $f$ there exists $a<d<b$ such that $h(a)<h(d)<y<h(b).$ Note that $h(d)=f(d)$ and $h(b)=f(b).$ Since $f$ satisfy the intermediate value theorem and $f(a)<y<f(b$) then there exists $a<d<x<b$ such that $h(x)=f(x)=y.$   Does that work? Any help will appreciated greatly.

Comment: Brian M.Scott. How this proof looks like to you ?